# ios provisioning profile valid signing identity not found

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, apple-push-notifications, vmware-workstation

i am developing an native ios application on mac os mavericks image on vmware, i am doing a training in a company. this application contain PushNotification service. i have download a video tutorial and i complete all the tasks as the video show. but in the end when i install the provisioning profile it show this warning message : "**valid signing identity not found**" . i have work on this issue many days. 
i am new in ios developing, so day by day i read questions of developers that have this issue also and i've read the answers and try to fix it but no result.
can anyone help me and guide what to do. down i will notice what i've see and i feel that this could be the problem and i can't do anything:
- when i create the provisioning profile , they gave me numbers of certificates to chose, none of these certificates is the one that i create.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many reasons for this message and many more potential solutions.

I often see this error message display when building. Quitting and restarting Xcode usually resolves the issue for me.

Comment: when the project building, it say that there is no certificate or key non-expire that match with the provisioning profile founded in the key chain

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the provisioning direct from apple site? Sometimes I have problems when I try to update directly from xcode.